# How can I interrup slow ajax request, running in background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, interrupt

The situation:

- User visit some fast loading page, that makes an AJAX async request to some slow PHP script, that loads, for example, for 30 seconds
- After 3 seconds user clicks some link to go to another fast loading page, but browser waits 27 seconds to finish AJAX request to slow script, and only after that starts to load next page

How can you solve this problem? How to tell web server to interrupt processing the request, started with defined AJAX call?

PS. abort() is not the solution

PPS. The code example: my page includes filter of shop products, that loads longer that other page components. After first load filter is cached - next times it loads fast. So when page loads, I don't show filter, but add a JS, that calls current page again using AJAX, adding some parameter (SHOW_FILTER). If page receive this parameter - it shows filter...

```
<div id="catalog_filter_container">
    <?if($_REQUEST['SHOW_FILTER'] == "Y"):?>
        ... filter code here ...
    <?endif;?>
</div>
<?if($_REQUEST['SHOW_FILTER'] != "Y"):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?=$APPLICATION->GetCurPageParam("SHOW_FILTER=Y", array("SHOW_FILTER")); // get cur URL with adding param SHOW_FILTER=Y ?>"
            })
            .done(function(html) {
            $("#catalog_filter_container").append($(html).find('#catalog_filter_container'));
            });
        });
    </script>
<?endif;?>
```

Comment: could you post the code you are working with ?

Comment: Ajax requests are asyncronous, how is the second point happening? Perhaps showing us some code may help. Also, side question: how is a php script taking 30 seconds? such heavy elaborations should not take place unless they are a must, else every user loading that specific page may encounter some further long loadings.

Comment: Are you talking about setting a timeout interval?

Comment: THe web request should be async, so that the client doesn't have to wait. That being said, I'm not aware of a default way to have the server interrupt its work. Apparently even a connection close doesn't stop server-side processing on all web servers. That being said, if you use a "task unique id" you could send a request to the server (in parallel to the first one) to have it stop the task in progress.

Comment: It's impossible to give you feedback without seeing any code, so please give us some code so we can help you :-)

Comment: Friends, I think, code won't help, because the question is most conceptual... Page loads, then, using jquery ajax() call I place some retrieved HTML (which generates not so fast) in specified div... I said about 30 seconds for example. My script loads for about 5-10 seconds first time, and next times - immediately, because of PHP cache usage.

Comment: The problem is that many people surf websites very fast, and when they click some link immediately after page opening, AJAX request is still processing, and browser waits... On each page my long loading script prepares different data, so caching it is not the full solution - if user quickly opens new pages (no one visited them today and no cache generated) - delays are present... So - the solution of the problem is to tell web server (apache, nginx...) to stop processing the request, recently made by AJAX

Comment: Here you can see how it works: http://www.dom-europe.ru/shop/. Under page title you will see loading, and after some seconds - filter appears. But if loading is not finished and you click some link - you will wait...

Comment: @DinoMyte I added information, thank you

Comment: @briosheje, I added information, thank you

Comment: @SeanKelleyx, I added information, thank you

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, I added information, thank you

Comment: @Lucero, I added information, thank you

Comment: What is the ... filter code here ... returning?  (what kind of data) You should at least include dataType when using $.ajax.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, filter code return HTML, of course. AJAX get whole page and then cut this generated HTML and insert it into container...

Comment: Ajax does not seem to be necessesary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it is not neccessary to have an ajax-call because the page is reloaded anyway. This seems like something you can do server-side only (with sessions).

Something like this: (If the thing you want to achieve is store a value to filter when filter not set and display the value from filter when it is set)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="catalog_filter_container">
<?if($_REQUEST['SHOW_FILTER'] == "Y") {
    $_SESSION['filter_content'] = 'bla bla bla';
}
else {
    echo $_SESSION['filter_content'];
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a cron job to run the queries separate from page loads and cache the results on the server. Then have your AJAX request return the cached content.